# N64 on digital TV

Tags: nintendo-64

I'm tying to use my old N64 with an 8 year old Samsung LCD TV. Upon plugging in the RCA video cable from the N64, the picture is incredibly pixelated.

I've read some things about how the n64 outputs a low quality video and the tvs are basically blowing up the low res images. And people get up converters and such.

Short of getting an old CRT tv, is there anything else I can try?  My TV also has HDMI in, VGA in and Antenna in. I tried an antenna / coaxial adapter for the N64 and the picture was only slightly better, but with added snow / distortion

Comment: if i recall the N64 could be connected by AV (Red, Yellow, White). you could get an AV to HDMI Upscaler but i can guarantee as currently the only AV to HDMI i do is with PS2s which would have better video output than a N64

Comment: Yea I'm currently connecting by red, yellow, white, which is where I'm experiencing the pixelated video.

Comment: Pixelated as in more so than usual? The thing doesn't exactly output high resolution video either way...

Comment: Yes. Quite pixelated and blurry. Apparently this is a known issue in modern TVs. I've compared it against screencasts of the same games being played on CRT TVS

Comment: The N64 uses a screen resolution of 256x224.  Modern HDTVs (not even 4ks) use the resolution 1920x1080.  Not really surprising that it's pixelated.  Old style CRTs kinda hid this because they were slightly blurry, which isn't the case for modern LCD/LED screens.

Comment: The n64 also has a notoriously bad anti-aliasing which basically smudges the entire screen. You won't be able to bypass that without modding or custom hardware solutions.

Comment: The N64 Screeen resolutions available were 320 x 240, up to 640x480. to improve performance or for special effects (ex. widescreen) developers could choose to use a smaller area of the screen. Indiana Jones and the Infernal Machine is known to use the higher resolution mode. The texture memory is still small which adds to the blurriness.

Answer (score 1):

The video solutions for the Nintendo 64 are covered pretty well with comparison video captured in this Youtube video [RGB205 Getting the Best Picture from your Nintendo 64 - MY LIFE IN GAMING](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpy1M6v2_MI)

I use an S-Video cable (same cable for SNES, N64, GC) make sure it has a [Ferrite Bead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) it really does help and is cheap (if not included). Less than $10 total and it looks good. Some games configured the internal video settings in a blurry or pixelated way so not much you can do with them.

There is an [HDMI modification](http://ultrahdmi.retroactive.be/) available that gets [amazing reviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6orhckbI7w), but is expensive and there is currently a waiting list.